# flex 4.6 : Pass Objects between views using actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I using flex 4.6 to build mobile application. i want to pass objects between views. i use in the first view

```
            User.name = Username.text;
            User.Pass = Password.text;
            navigator.pushView(views.masterHomeView , User)
```

and in the second view

```
    <s:Label id="b" text="{data.name}"/>
    <s:Label id="lbl" text="{data.Pass}"  />
```

and it worked well for represent the data in the labels , but i want to review the object in the action script not in mxml to pass values of object to function

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your view override public function set data(value:Object):void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by using

```
            override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            var x = value.name;
            var y = value.Pass;
        }
```

Comment: Make sure to super.data = value; on the first line or you may run into issues.